# MomentJS - Set time to start of next quarter while retaining same/comparative calendar day?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

Let's say I have a dateString such as:

```
const currentTime = "2020-08-31T00:00:00Z"
```

I want to be able to find the start of the next quarter while retaining the calendar day or intuitively adjust if its the last day of the month. Expected time:

```
const nextTime = "2020-09-30T00:00:00Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give current quarter number

```
const current_quarter= moment().quarter();
```

This will give you start date of next quarter

```
const start = moment().quarter(current_quarter+1).startOf('quarter');
```

You can always get current date and time using

```
const today = moment();
```

Comment: Thanks! While this does give me the start of the quarter, it does not help retain the same calendar day which is what I'm expecting.

Comment: you can get current date using const today = moment();